# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE with PostgreSQL COPY FROM command

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I am very new to PostgreSQL. Actually I was using MySQL before but for some project specific reason I need to use postgreSQL and do a POC.

Now the problem is:
I was using MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE command to load the column content from a file to my database table.

My table structure is :
Table name: MSISDN
Table Column Names: ID(primary key - auto_generated), JOB_ID, MSISDN, REGION, STATUS

But my input text file(rawBase.txt) is having only below columns:
MSISDN, REGION

so I was using the below command to load these above 2 column with initial JOB_ID and STATUS.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:\\project\\rawBase.txt' INTO TABLE MSISDN 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(MSISDN,REGION) 
SET JOB_ID = 'XYZ1374147779999', STATUS = 0;
```

as you can see that there is a option available in LOAD DATA INFILE command where I can SET a particular initial value for the columns which are not present(JOB_ID and STATUS) in the input text file.

NOW,

in case of postgreSQL, I want same thing to happen.

There is also a same kind of command available COPY FROM 
like below:

```
COPY MSISDN FROM 'D:\\project\\rawBase.txt' WITH DELIMITER AS ','
```

but I am not able to SET a particular initial value for the rest columns which are not present(JOB_ID and STATUS) in my input text file. I am not getting any fruitful example of doing this.

Please give some suggestion if possible.

Regards,
Sandy

Comment: Can you load your data into a temporary table and copy it from temporary table to a real one with `INSERT ... SELECT ... `?

Comment: lgor.. Thanks for the comment but as the file copy is for very huge record Hence using of temporary table will be time consuming task.

Answer (score 3):

You may do it the "Unix way" using pipes:

```
cat rawbase.txt | awk '{print $0",XYZ1374147779999,0"}' | psql -d dbname -c "copy MSISDN FROM stdin with delimiter AS ','"
```

Now from the file paths in the question it appears you're using MS-Windows, but a Unix shell and command-line tools like `awk` are available for Windows through [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) or [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Answer (score 2):

`COPY` with a column-list, and set a `DEFAULT` on the table columns you don't specify.

```
regress=> CREATE TABLE copydemo(a text not null, b text not null default 'blah');

regres=> \COPY copydemo(a) FROM stdin
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> blah
>> otherblah
>> \.
regres=> SELECT * FROM copydemo;
     a     |  b   
-----------+------
 blah      | blah
 otherblah | blah
(2 rows)
```

You're probably `COPY`ing from a file rather than stdin; I just did it on stdin for a quick demo of what I mean. The key thing is that columns that require values not in the CSV have `DEFAULT`s set, and you specify a column-list in `COPY`, eg `COPY (col1, col2)`.

There is unfortunately no equivalent to the COPY-specific `SET` that you want there. You can stage via a temporary table and do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, as Igor suggested, if you can't or don't want to `ALTER` your table to set column `DEFAULT`s.

Comment: Craig.. Thanks for the comment but the default will not work for me. as the initial value for job_id will be different for each file copy.

Comment: @Sandy In Postgres `ALTER TABLE` statement is transactional. You can set it at the start of a transaction for every import job and they wont interfere with each other. And, at the end of transaction - just revert to old defaults.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko That's half-correct. `ALTER TABLE` is transactional, but *it takes an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table* that prevents concurrent reads and writes. So you can roll it back, sure, but it's still plenty disruptive. In this case the best option is to follow your suggestion - stage to a temp table, then do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` as I outlined above.