# How to work with huge CSV file (3.5GB) with github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, github, large-files

I have a RoR project where I have to populate the database with huge 3.5GB CSV file.

I can't upload 3.5GB to github but I have to use it, plus working with such a huge file is hard memory vise.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think you might be looking for Git LFS https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: I wouldn't crunch a 3.5gb CSV file in production. Do it on your local machine and export a database dump with pgbackups or split into smaller csv files that can be batch imported.

Comment: Seed databases and snapshots are not generally bundled in `git` repositories because they make future clones of the repo cripplingly slow, *especially* if you drop something that heavy in them. Why not pre-process this and have it available as a separate download from a server you control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually do this some what frequently. There are some thing you need to consider when attempting something like this:

-Does this app get a lot of external user traffic or critical internal user traffic?

-Are there business implications to this server being bogged down for this long running job?

-Does the server this app is hosted on have the resources required (memory and hard drive space) to process a job like this?

-Do you have SCP access to the host server to transfer the file to the server?

Once you have a good understanding of the above you should do the following.

1. Write a CSV import script (probably a rake task), don’t use the default ruby CSV library use something like [faster cvs](https://github.com/JEG2/faster_csv) or [smarter cvs](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) (they are faster). Ensure that when writing the import script you use the library’s enumerator function that will avoid loading the entire spreadsheet in memory (foreach). Also since this is going to probably be a long running job put some feed back output (like puts or a counter) so that you have some insight to whats going on.
2. Test the script out on your local with the actual spreadsheet, I don’t know what the data integrity is like but in spreadsheet that large you could run into character encoding issues. It is best to figure that out without having had a bunch of failed runs on production cluttering up you database.
3. Deploy your code
4. Compress the CSV
5. Transfer the compressed CSV to your designated directory
6. Uncompress the CSV
7. Run the import script
8. Check the data for signs of a successful import like the difference in records.
9. Delete the CSV

Comment: Thank very much for your really well written answer.

Can I ask you what tool do you usually use for compressing CSV I ended up using Heorku PG Backups. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Comment: I am usually running on ubuntu so I just create tar files see here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-howto-compress-files-using-tar/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is absolutely no reason to commit your data to Git. You should be using a `migration`

Since your data is huge, you can simply use the Database directly to load your data. You may have to ensure your CSV is correctly formatted but that is trivial.

Depending on your Database you can use LOAD DATA or COPY, see this SO question for that
[MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE with PostgreSQL COPY FROM command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803999/mysql-load-data-infile-with-postgresql-copy-from-command)

Comment: Even tho I didn't accepted your answer as the main one, I wanted to thank you because your answer was the fastest and led me to use Heroku PG Backups which solved my problem. Thank you very much.